# Make touchcancel event a touchend using HammerJS

Tags: javascript, touch, hammer.js

I have a webapp running in Google Chrome Browser that runs fine on Windows 7 with a touchscreen, however on a Windows 8 tablet the touch events don't work in the same way.

It is much more sensitive to any movement of the touch which often results in a touchcancel event being fired instead of a touchend.

I'd like to map all touchcancel events to be a touchend. The app uses Hammer JS as I hoped it would cover situations like this. Does anybody have a method to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Got a much better experience on the events by changing the hammer defaults setting especially around the tap settings to make a larger threshold for a touch tap event which translates through to a touchend.